# How can i call the data.length every time the app restarts?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, sqflite

**From the source code which uses SQFlite attached. Once we add a item to cart the cart.length = 1 but once we restart the app, the length becomes 0 and when we re-add the item to the list, cart.length = 2. **
[making cart list using sqflite](https://github.com/hupptechnologies/shopping-app-with-cart-flutter-demo)

**How can i call the data.length every time the app restarts?**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that returns the quantity of items you have on your database and call this function on initState of your cart page.